# Сравнить два двумерных массива и при совпадении вывести один из ключей

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день помогите, такой вопрос
 есть два массива

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:16:07
             [1] => 5266
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:16:09
             [1] => 1576
         )

     [2] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:16:15
             [1] => 9574
         )

     [3] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:17:35
             [1] => 3713
         )

)
```

и

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:17:20
             [1] => 1576
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => 6:17:27
             [1] => 9574
         )

)
```

нужно сравнить ключи 
 в первом и во втором массиве

```
[0] => Array
          (
              [1] => 5266
          )
```

и вывести
 время обоих массивов

то есть
 находим что в первом массиве совпадает число 1576

```
[1] => Array
          (
              [0] => 6:16:09
              [1] => 1576
          )
```

совпадает со вторым числом 1576

```
[0] => Array
          (
              [0] => 6:17:20
              [1] => 1576
          )
```

и выводим
 6:16:09 и 6:17:20
 и так далее в массиве по 500 таких данных

дошло но немного не правильно работает :(

```
 foreach( $data1 as $key=>$header )
        { 
        foreach( $data2 as $key2=>$header2 )
            {
            if ($header1 = $header2)
            {
            echo $header2[0] . ' - '. $header1[0] .' '. $header1[1] .' '. $header2[1] . '<br>';
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1. Сделать ключи типа 1576 ключами массива
2. Применить `array_intersect_key()` на обоих
3. Применить `array_diff_assoc()`  и получить массив-разницу

Comment: @Etki, что-то тут не то. ТС-у нужно получить значения из обоих массивов. Как тут поможет "array_diff_assoc" - понять не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насколько решение можно назвать элегантным, но вроде бы работает. Потестируйте на своих реальных массивах.

```
$total = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
$tmp = array();
foreach($total as $v){
  $tmp[$v[1]][] = $v[0];
}
$result = array_filter($tmp, function($a){
    return count($a) > 1;
});
print_r($result);
```

Результат - двумерный массив, где каждый вложенный имеет ключ из совпавших и два значения из обоих массивов:

```
Array
(
    [1576] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6:16:09
            [1] => 6:17:20
        )

    [9574] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6:16:15
            [1] => 6:17:27
        )

)
```

Comment: сори забыл написать что 1576 и другие в 1 массиве могут повторятся
только как убрать повторения

Comment: @Night Wolf, в данном случае - это без разницы. Просто будет во вложенном массиве больше значений.

Comment: спасибо сейчас опробую

Comment: @Night Wolf, набросал [пример в песочнице][1]

   [1]:http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/en87-txip

Comment: прям то что нужно :) спасибо большое

Comment: @Night Wolf, немного подправил условие в фильтре.